# Running a list index in python but nothing shows... why?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
spam = ['cat','dog','bat']
spam.insert(0,'poo')
spam
```

this is my code, why is there nothing showing after I run this program?

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python output", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
print(spam)
```

to show the content of "spam". Writing "spam" won't change anything.

Comment: I've seen an instance where someone did a very similar quote and put spam which had the same output

Comment: if you run python3 on the terminal it will probably show the content of the variable by typing "spam" only, but when you run as a program this is the way.